# Change routeconfig

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

In the RouteConfig-file I see :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Which then maps in my controller to

```
public Person Get(int id)
{
    return _personService.GetPersoonByInszNumber("11111111111");
}
```

Now I would like to change this so it maps to the following :

```
public Person Get(string inszNumber)
{
    return _personService.GetPersoonByInszNumber(inszNumber);
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Just call your argument id, I don't believe the type matters in the routing config, only the name. so Get(string id)

Comment: Do you want to keep both action methods? Or do you just trying to refactor existed one?

Comment: But when he invoke  Home/Index/id=2323  - > first match always by a method with string  argument

Comment: We will be requiring both actions. So one with the string and one with the id.

Comment: @BartSchelkens What version of MVC are you using? In MVC5 this can easily be done using attribute routing.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev We are using MVC5

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using [attrubute routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx):

```
[Route("Persons/Get/{id:int}")]
public Person Get(int id)
{
    ....
}

[Route("Persons/Get/{inszNumber}")]
public Person Get(string inszNumber)
{
    ....
}
```

Just add appropriate attributes (here I'm supposing your controller name is `PersonsController`. In other case change it appropriately) to your actions.

Also make sure you have this line of code in `RegisterRoutes` method just before default route declaration:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Comment: I did what you suggested, but now I'm always coming through the 
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
which is not what I expected.

Comment: Hmm... you haven't mentioned existence of one more action having the same name in question... Anyway - if you set attributes for two mentioned actions and left this `IEnumerable<string> Get()` without any attribute - it should work as intended. At least at my side in sample project request goes to the action with int argument on `Persons/Get/1`, to the action with string argument on `Persons/Get/ttt` and to the action without arguments on `Persons/Get`

Comment: Sorry that i forgot to mention the action :-( my bad.
But i still have the problem that now I always go through the get without parameters.

Comment: It's very strange. Update your question with relevant code from your controller as well as from `RegisterRoutes` you have right now - maybe there is something wrong there....

Comment: Probably there is a mismatch with your controller name and prefix in routing attribute. I've used `Persons/Get` in these attributes assumint your controller class name is `PersonsController`. If it is different - you have to change it in attributes, else these actions marked with attributes will not be called.